# CS50 tideman - :( lock_pairs skips final pair if it creates cycle

Tags: c, cs50

I'm new to stackoverflow and pretty new to programming.
I'm working on the tideman problem for the CS50 course. https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/3/tideman/
When I run check50 everything checks out except for one:

:( lock_pairs skips final pair if it creates cycle
lock_pairs did not correctly lock all non-cyclical pairs

These two do pass the test:
:) lock_pairs locks all pairs when no cycles
:) lock_pairs skips middle pair if it creates a cycle

I can't find the problem. What am I missing here?

This is my code:

```
// Each pair has a winner, loser
typedef struct
{
    int winner;
    int loser;
}
pair;

// Array of candidates
string candidates[MAX];
pair pairs[MAX * (MAX - 1) / 2];

    // Lock pairs into the candidate graph in order, without creating cycles
void lock_pairs(void)
{
    // for every pair we need to check for a circle
    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
    {
        if (!circle_check(pairs[i].winner, pairs[i].loser))
        {
            //there's no circle: lock in pair
            locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;
        }
    }
}


// check pair for circles between winner and loser. Loser is first link
bool circle_check(int winner, int link)
{
    // check if the loser already has connections
    for (int n = 0; n < candidate_count; n++)
    {
        if (locked[link][n] == true)
        {
            // there's a link. if this ends in the winner, there's a circle
            if (n == winner)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                // there may still be a circle, check next connection
                link = n;
                circle_check(winner, link);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A few observations about your code/logic:

1. You are altering the value of your function argument in `circle_check` when you do `link = n`. It's good practice to not alter what's passed in as an argument in a function. Plus, on this specific case, you could do `circle_check(winner, n)` directly.
2. Your `circle_check` function, as it is presented, **always** returns false. That happens because when you call it from itself, you're not actually using it's return for anything. Let's say that recursive call returns **true**: On the 'first' function call, the line could be replaced by:

```c
else
{
  link = n;
  true;
}
```

And, as you can imagine, that does nothing and the function continues it's execution normally, returning false.

If you, instead, add a `return` in front of the function call, you solve this problem.

But then there's also a 3rd point, that you need to consider:

3. Your function does not account for multiple checks for links on the same line of the `locked[i][j]` matrix. Allow me to demonstrate:

Imagine you have a 5x5 locked matrix, and on line 4 you currently have this disposition of true (T) and false (F):

[ F  T  T  X  F  ]

When your function linear searches through the line, it's going to stop on locked[4][1], the first true, and do the recursive call to find a link. If it does find, it's going to return **true** and your `lock_pairs` is not going to add true to the `locked` matrix. But, what if it doesn't find? Then, instead of going to `locked[4][2]` to check for links there, it's just going to return `false` and the pair is going to be locked on `lock_pairs`.

You could solve this, for example, by adding a check after the recursive call, to see if it was returned true or false there. If true is returned, it means there's a link and you should NOT add the pair to `locked`. On the other hand, if you get false, it means there's no link and you can continue the linear search on the line.

The `else` statement could look something like:

```c
else
{
  if (circle_check(winner,n)) // this way it only stops the search if a link was found
  {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: The first two point I got straight away. The third was a bit more difficult to grasp, but I get is now. And it works. I spend many hours on this, so thank you for taking the time to help me out, and for explaining it so well.

Comment: Glad it helped you :)